# populating instance of mongoose model

Tags: javascript, mongoose

Can I do `.populate()` on instance of mongoose model that I already did `.find()`?
So this is the school example:

```
Model.findById(id).populate("bar").exec(function(err, document){
   doSth(document);
});
```

But I would like to do my `.find()` separately in middleware, and pass the result if needed to block that will `.populate()` it. Sth like this:

```
var foo;
Model.findById(id, function(err, document){
   foo = document;
});

foo.populate("bar");
doSth(foo);
```

or:

```
foo.populate("bar").exec(function(err, document){
   doSth(document);
});
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this

```
foo.populate('bar', function(err) {
 console.log(foo.bar);
});
```

I found this solution [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/wiki/3.6-Release-Notes#population). Let me know if it helps you.

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

There are indeed multiple ways:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-populate

It's important if you're using async/await, to not forget to add `.execPopulate()`, like:

```
let foo = await Foo.findOne({}).exec()
await foo.populate('bar').execPopulate()
```